# Math.min.apply(0, array) - why?

Tags: javascript

I was just digging through some JavaScript code (Raphaël.js) and came across the following line (translated slightly):

```
Math.min.apply(0, x)
```

where `x` is an array. Why on earth would you do this? The behavior seems to be "take the min from the array `x`."

Comment: Math.min.apply(this, x) would do as well

Comment: Shorter and less confusing today would be: `Math.min(...x)`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I realized the answer as I was posting my own question: This *is* the most succinct way of taking the min of an array `x` in JavaScript. The first argument is totally arbitrary; I find the 0 confusing because the code intuitively means "Take the min of 0 and x," which is absolutely not the case. Using the Math object makes more sense for human-readability, but the Raphael.js authors are obsessed with minification and 0 is three bytes shorter.

See http://ejohn.org/blog/fast-javascript-maxmin/

For readability's sake, I'd strongly urge people to stop doing this and instead define a function along the lines of

```
function arrayMin(arr) { return Math.min.apply(Math, arr); };
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the "0" in the Raphael code represents the scope that Math.min is executed with. The reason this "should" be Math is because that's the native/natural scope for that method when normally invoked. Using zero presumably is equivalent to null there, which is equivalent to the global object (window). This works fine assuming that the method doesn't need access to internal state of the Math object, which is probably a safe assumption, but is still an assumption. Don't use that pattern yourself if you can help it. As you (Trevor) note, use Math there.

Comment: Correction to the above: Using zero here is not equivalent to null. It is semantically goofy, and results in the scope being a Number object representing zero, which is basically worthless. This keeps character count to a minimum, but still makes an assumption about the inner workings of "min".

Comment: Minification? Is that really a word?  :)

Comment: @GregS, it used to be called using-various-and-sundries-coding-techniques-and-automatic-code-processing-tools-to-reduce-the-file-that-will-be-sent-to-the-client-to-the-smallest-reasonably-achievable-size. Then it was called uvasctaacpttrtftwbsttcttsras for short. The pronunciation of the acronym naturally morphed into the word minification.

Comment: Thanks quixoto, and thanks for the laugh jball. I am now smarter, I think.

Answer (score 14):

The reason is this:

- Your input `x` is an array
- The signature of `Math.min()` doesn't take arrays, only comma separated arguments
- If you were using `Function.prototype.call()` it would have almost the same signature, except the first argument is the `this` context, *i.e.* who's "calling"

  - Example: `Math.min.call(context, num1, num2, num3)`
- The `context` only matters when you refer to `this` inside the function, *e.g.* most methods you can call on an array: `Array.prototype.<method>` would refer to `this` (the array to the left of the 'dot') inside the method.
- `Function.prototype.apply()` is very similar to `.call()`, only that instead of taking comma-separated arguments, it now takes an array after the `context`.

  - `Function.prototype.call(context, arg1, arg2, arg3)`
  - `Function.prototype.apply(context, [arg1, arg2, arg3])`
- The `0` or `null` that you put in as the first argument is just a place shifter.

Answer (score 1):

The proper and less confusing way to call this is:
Math.min.apply(null, array)

If parameter is unused setting it to null makes code more readable than setting it to 0 or Math

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: could you explain detail the first argument ? I try: var numbers = [5, 6, 7, 2, 3];
var max1 = Math.max.apply(4, numbers); var max2 = Math.max.apply(9, numbers); var max3 = Math.max.apply(null, numbers); but I don't see difference result of max1, max2, max3. So, How do I do to receive difference result with my example?

Comment: Just want to mention that according to the link null only works in non-strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where we can get the MAX and MIN timezone offsets for the given year for a timezone. It returns the two changes for the year to account for DST and ST. (i.e. ST = 300 an DST = 360 for the timezone in question).

```
   var arr = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < 365; i++) {
       var d = new Date();
       d.setDate(i);
       var newoffset = d.getTimezoneOffset();
       arr.push(newoffset);
   }
   var DST = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
   var nonDST = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
   tw.local.stInt = DST
   tw.local.edInt = nonDST
```

Comment: Can anyone tell me the difference between calling Math.min.apply(null, arr) and Math.min.apply(Math, arr). How will null invocation context work with apply? The native context for min method is Math object and it makes more sense to use Math as the first argument for apply method.