# Minimum number excluding zero

Tags: javascript

I need to find minimum number from list of numbers, excluding zero(s).

Is there some internal function that would do that? Or do I have to remove zero(s) from list before `Math.min` is used?

*Example:*

Input: `213`, `0`, `32`, `92`, `0`, `2992`, `39`

Result: `32`

---

**[UPDATE]** If possible, please provide code for function that would take inputs as arguments, such as `nonZeroMin(213, 0, 32, 92, 0, 2992, 39)`

Comment: where does the input come from? an array? continuous input? string?

Comment: I've updated my answer to accept arguments as per your update.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Code/Solution:*

```
var arr = [3, 0, 7, 12, 0, 5, 22];
var minValue = Math.min.apply(null, arr.filter(Boolean));
```

*How it works:*

`arr.filter` creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function. So in the code above each value of the array will be tested by `Boolean(value)`

```
Boolean(3) // true 
Boolean(0) // false
Boolean(7) // true
// ...
```

So as a result we will have new filtered array with all elements except zeros.

Then `Math.min.apply(null, ...)` find min value in such array.

`null` is in this case a context. It can be `null`, `this`, `Math` - result will be the same.

Comment: ES6 version could be something like: `function nonZeroMin(...numbers) {
  return Math.min(...numbers.filter(Boolean));
}`

Answer (score 10):

```
var arr = [213, 0, 32, 92, 0, 2992, 39];

var min = arr.filter(function (x) { return x !== 0; })
    .reduce(function (a, b) { return Math.min(a, b); }, Infinity); 

alert(min);  // => 32
```

`filter` and `reduce` are EcmaScript 5 additions to `Array`, but `MDN` provides [code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for them in case you need to run this on older browsers.

---

EDIT: Here's a shorter way that works in a var-args style function.

```
 function minNonZero(var_args) {
   return Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, function (prev, current) {
     return prev && current ? Math.min(prev, current) : prev || current;
   });
 }

 alert(minNonZero(213, 0, 32, 92, 0, 2992, 39));
```

Comment: ...I don't even know where to start with this. What does *everything* mean? Well, specifically the `filter` function, which I've never heard of, the `reduce` function, which I've never heard of, and the `!!x` operation, which I've never heard of.

Comment: `arr.filter(...)` returns an array containing only the elements that don't match the function passed in, so an array with every element except 0.  `reduce` then walks over the array and applies the function to each element and the value from the last call.  Since I passed in a function that is essentially `Math.min`, it returns the minimum of the filtered array.

Comment: Ah, okay. What's `!!x` do anyhow? I see that you've edited it out, but I still what to know what it does. :)

Comment: Wouldn't `Math.min.apply(Math, arr.filter(function (x) { return x !== 0; }))` be better? :-P

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: `!!` converts things into booleans.  It basically negates it twice.  `!!0 = !(!0) = !(true) = false`.

Comment: @Rocket, nice.  I didn't think of that.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville, yeah too clever, which is why I edited it out.  I also wanted to filter out only zeroes as per the OP, not NaNs too.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: I love one-liners :-P

Comment: @MikeSamuel: Ah, okay. Also, wasn't my question. :)

Comment: Would you use similar approach to code function that would exclude undefined elements?

Comment: Infinity ? What is this ? It is like MAX_INT ?

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj: Pretty much.  It's to make sure that the first iteration always returns the number from the array as the "min".

Comment: Since OP wanted multiple args instead of an array for some reason, you could handle that with a test - if the argument is not an Array, use `arguments` instead.

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj, Positive infinity is an [IEEE-754](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html#infinity) value that is greater than all values but itself and NaN.  It is the result of `1/+0`.

Comment: @MarkReed, Added a var_args version that does away with the filter as well.

Answer (score 8):

How about this?

```
var arry = [213, 0, 32, 92, 0, 2992, 39];
Math.min.apply(Math, arry.filter(Number)); // => 32
```

Comment: I like this concept. But why to use `Math` for argument `this`? Why not just `Math.min.apply(0, arry.filter(Number))` ?

Comment: You'll find some discussion here as to why use Math vs 0 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870015/math-min-apply0-array-why

Comment: This answer is much more flexible and requires less code, it can also be slightly modified to provide different results for other scenarios

Answer (score 6):

you can filter for positive numbers except zero and sort the array:

```
list.filter(function(x){ 
    return x> 0;
}).sort(function(a,b){
   return a>b;
})[0];
```

Comment: Wow, that's a really slick solution! +1

Comment: Note: Change `>0` to `!==0` if you want to support negative numbers.

Comment: The return value of sort should be: `return a > b ? 1 : (a == b ? 0 : -1);`

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to remove zeroes and then use `Math.min`, like this:

```
function nonZeroMin() { // input can be as many parameters as you want
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    for(var i = args.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if(args[i] == 0) args.splice(i, 1);
    }

    return Math.min.apply(null,args);
}
```

Edited to allow input parameters as per updated question.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make a function that takes an unknown number of arguments, you can use [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) from inside that function.

To find the lowest non-zero number, you can sort the array, and sort zeros (and non-numbers) to the end.

```
function nonZeroMin(){
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    args.sort(function(a, b){
        if(a === null || isNaN(a) || a === 0) return 1;
        if(b === null || isNaN(b) || b === 0) return -1
        return a-b;
    });
    return args[0];
}
```

Then you can do: `nonZeroMin(213, 0, 32, 92, 0, 2992, 39)`.

Comment: Heh, you used the same technique I did. :) +1

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: Yep.  Pretty sure it's the only way to handle an unknown number of parameters in a function :-P

Comment: What modification would be needed if I need to filter undefined items instead of zero(s), please?

Comment: @user1215106: Change the `if` statements in the `sort` function to check for that.  Check my answer now, I added `isNaN`, which checks to see if the value is "not a number".

Comment: you mean conditions in both `if` lines?