# Find if a certain data type exists in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I had to make a function that finds the smallest number among a mixed elements in an array:

```
function findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(arr) {
    if (arr.length === 0) {
        return 0;
    }
  var num_arr = arr.filter(e => { return typeof e === 'number'});

  return num_arr.sort( (a, b) => { return a - b})[0];

}

var output = findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements([4, 'lincoln', 9, 'octopus']);
console.log(output); // --> 4
```

Seems to be working, but I'm failing a test, I have to return `0` if no numbers exists in the array. I'm trying to figure out a simple way to write it with the if statement at the beginning but I can't find a straightforward answer. Was thinking of something with `includes` but it seems that `includes` looks for a specific element not a data type. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557176/minimum-number-excluding-zero

Comment: `array.every(elm => typeof elm !== 'number')` to check if all elements are *not* numbers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use array.reduce() to do it

```js
function findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements(arr) {
    let result = arr.reduce(function(a, b){
        if(typeof b != 'number')
            return a;
        if(typeof a != 'number')
            return b;
        return a<b ? a : b;
    })
    return (typeof result == 'number' ? result : 0);
}

var output = findSmallestNumberAmongMixedElements([4, 'lincoln', 9, 'octopus']);
console.log(output);
```