# why set the Math object as context?

Tags: javascript

To find minimum of an array of numbers in JavaScript we do something like this:

```
var min_val = Math.min.apply(Math, [12,3,5,7,-1]);
```

Any conceivable reason you'd want to pass the Math object here?

Edit:

Still unclear where such a pattern makes sense

> *foo*.fun.apply(*foo*, array)

Comment: In that case I don't think is very useful, you could just pass `0`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Math.min.apply(0, array) - why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870015/math-min-apply0-array-why)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to pass `Math` here.

Answering your edit:

> Still unclear where such a pattern makes sense: `foo.fun.apply(foo,
>   array)`

Let's try to demonstrate by example:

```
var foo  = { 
             fun: function(a,b,c){ console.log(this.bar, [a,b,c]); }, 
             whatsthis: function(){ console.log(this);}, 
             bar: 5 
           };
var bar = {bar: 10};
foo.fun.apply(null, [1,2,3]); //=> prints undefined, [1,2,3]. Why?
foo.whatsthis.apply(null);    //=> aha: prints Window
foo.fun.apply(foo, [1,2,3]);  //=> prints 5, [1,2,3]
// apply foo.fun within bar context:
foo.fun.apply(bar, [1,2,3]);  //=> prints 10, [1,2,3]
```

So, `foo.fun.apply` executes `foo.fun` in the global scope (`window`) and therefore will need a context (scope) to be able to refer to properties of a context (`foo` or `bar`).

Answer (score 1):

`Math.min` internal implementation could use `this`. So it's better to keep it.

AFAIK, that's the case with `document.getElementById` (and others): you can't just do `$ = document.getElementById`, it throws `TypeError: Illegal invocation` when I call it.

Comment: 1) What for? 2) Unless DOCUMENTATION says so any "internal" details must never be taken in consideration.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov, so you know all these documentation details? As for me, it's a lot easier to call `apply` in right context than remember (or go and check it when coding).

Comment: Well why, section 15.8.2.12 of ECMAScript standard edition 5 will tell you everything about `Math.min`. Saying anything not mentioned there or in specific environment release notes would be spreading misinformation for no good reason.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov, I don't doubt in standard. But do you refer to it on every line? I think, it's more "bug-proof" to do the way stated in the question than otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I do, unless specific engine notes say otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument is, in this case, arbitrary:

```
console.log( Math.min.apply(Math, [12,3,5,7,-1]) );
console.log( Math.min.apply(null, [12,3,5,7,-1]) );
console.log( Math.min.apply(0, [12,3,5,7,-1]) );
console.log( Math.min.apply(undefined, [12,3,5,7,-1]) );
console.log( Math.min.apply(-10, [12,3,5,7,-1]) );
```

All the above output `-1`.

So there is no particular reason to pass the `Math` object in this instance.

**Edit**

The pattern `foo.fun.apply( foo, array )` makes sense when passing arguments from one function to another:

```
wrapper = function(){
  // call foo.fun() with the same arguments as were
  // passed to the wrapper function.
  var rtn = foo.fun.apply( foo, arguments );

  // do something with the return value.
}
```

You can also use it when dynamically defining the arguments to a function (the example is a little contrived but hopefully it gives you the idea):

```
var values = [],
    foo = {
      set: function(){ this.inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 0 ); },
      sum: function(){
             var i=0,total=0;
             for ( ; i < this.inputs.length; ++i )
               total += this.inputs[i];
             return total;
           },
      inputs: []
    };

console.log( foo.sum() ); // Outputs 0

// Get user to add values from somewhere (i.e. a HTML input field)
values.push(1);
values.push(2);
// Once finished call foo.set
foo.set.apply( foo, values );

console.log( foo.sum() ); // Outputs 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is because you have to. Apply takes the context for the method as the first argument. I believe Math.min is also available in the global scope so you could write

```
Math.min.apply(null,[12,3,5,7,-1]);
```

There's other ways to write it that don't require you to do that (for example, you could just write Math.min([12,3,5,7,-1]) ), but it all depends on what you're doing with this.

You can find more details about apply and context [here](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/function/apply).

Comment: `Math.min( [12,3,5,7,-1] )` returns `NaN`

Comment: Oops, you're right. That should be Math.min(12,3,5,7,-1).  No square brackets. Math.min expects the arguments to be one or more numbers, not an array.