# Math.min give NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating array using `$.map` as below

```
var correctScores = $('[id^="dvAns_"] input[type="text"]').map(function () {
   return $(this).val().trim() == "" ? 0 : parseFloat($(this).val());
}).get();
```

it gives me array as `[5, 0]`

when I am writing `Math.min(correctScores)` it returns `NaN` instead of 0.

Why so?

Comment: @Sudhir: have you provided a link to the already existing solution when you marked this post as duplicate? Where would I find the already existing solution if hadn't provided it in my post? -- Sorry: found it! It was right at the top!!!! Silly me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use `apply` to be able to use `Math.min()` in connection with an array. In its native form it expects individual arguments.

See here: [Math.min.apply(0, array) - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870015/math-min-apply0-array-why)

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be out of array, like this;

```
Math.min(correctScores[0],correctScores[1]); // 0
```

Comment: Or `Math.min.apply(null, correctScores)`

Comment: There are many things that idk of javascript yet... this is one of them, thanks!